# Clear button pressed color in UISearchBar

Tags: xcode, button, searchbar, tintcolor

[image]

How can I change the blue color of clear button when it's pressed?

I'm using this

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

which changes the color of the blink | and of "Cancel" button, but it does not change that blue color.

EDIT: You can just see that Facebook.app does this (the color is white)